# How to hide scroll bar on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have developed a single page website with 4 sections. Here is what my client wants:

1. The scrollbar should be hidden on page load
2. If the user scrolls past the second section, the scrollbar should appear.

My client gave me this website as an example: http://diagnosite.com/

How can I do this?

Comment: Is your client sure they want this? Have you advised the client that the appeareance of a scrollbar at a certain point could cause small movements in the page structure like a slight shift to the left?

Comment: i have asked this many times but he is sure that he want this he also provide me reference site : http://diagnosite.com

Comment: Open this in chrome please. .

Comment: What you did for same, are you using bootstrap or anything else for view side.

Answer (score 2):

you can set overflow:hidden; for your body and have a javascript to detect scroll down from viewer mouse or pagedown button from keybiard. then remove overflow attribute from body.

Comment: but if i set overflow hidden it will stop scrolling .

Comment: that's why you have to add javascript listener to mouse scroll down . if you detect that viewer turn his mouse scroll down you will remove overflow so scrollbar will appear. if you dont want to appear at all just visibility hidden scroll bar wih css